# Why does the group velocity of 2D plasmon diverge at small wave number?

Tags: special-relativity, plasmon

Now plasma represents collective wave-like motions of charged particles. In 3D, their frequency is well known to be almost a constant, $\omega^{3D}_p \approx \sqrt{4\pi n e^2/m}$, with $n$=charge density, $m$=particle mass. However, in 2D, one can show that it becomes $\omega^{2D}_p \sim \sqrt{q}$, where $q$= wave number. It gets dispersion. The group velocity is then $v^{2D}_g \sim 1/\sqrt{q}$, which diverges as $q\rightarrow 0$. How could this be possible ? How could $v^{2D}_g$ exceed the speed of light, which is ridiculous to me ?

Highly appreciate your attention !!

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Consider adding references in order to receive useful and focused answers.

Comment: Please could you give the proportionality constant which appears in $v_g^{2D}$? This should tell us at which wavelengths the group velocity approaches $c$. Presumably this is also a length scale at which the effective theory you are using becomes invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Here is a reference: http://rmf.smf.mx/pdf/rmf/39/4/39_4_640.pdf

Comment: More precisely, $\omega^{2D}_p \approx \sqrt{2\pi ne^2/m} ~ \sqrt{q}$. There is a limit on the validity of these formula only in large $q$.